# Easiest way ever to create bitmap in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

Sometimes it is required to create a dummy bitmap for test purposes. To make the bitmap discernable (e. g. a red one and green one), I am searching for a way to create a `wx.Bitmap` with as few lines of code as possible.

What I did come up with sofar:

```
size_h_w = 64
bmp1 = wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(size_h_w, size_h_w, red=255, alpha=1)
bmp2 = wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(size_h_w, size_h_w, green=255, alpha=0)
```

However, the only thing I get with this is a black and transparent bitmap. How to make the color argument work?

Target is from `wxPython 2.9` onward (`wxMSW`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `alpha=255` (or `wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE`). That is the alpha level for fully opaque.  Zero is fully transparent, and one is almost fully transparent.

Comment: +1 for the named constant. What I am still struggling with: When setting ``wx.ALPHA_TRANSPARENT``/0, the bitmap (used in a ``wx.StaticBitmap``) will always be black (no matter what color). When alpha is nonzero, e. g. 1, the background will shine through. Bug or feature?

Comment: He said that the lower the value, the more transparent it will be. Try 255.

Comment: @nepix32, it depends on what the image is being used for.  In some cases (platform, widget type, how it is drawn, etc.) the alpha may be ignored, or in other cases if the image has nothing but pixels with 0 or 255 alpha then it will be converted to a wxMask instead.